# Configurable Swatches is impacting Performance of the website drastically

Tags: configurable-product, performance, swatches

We are using Magento 1.9.1.4 CE and struggling to improvise the performance of the web pages primarily on the Checkout Page and Shopping Cart.

When analyzing these web pages in terms of performance it appears that:

`Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Mediafallback::attachConfigurableProductChildrenAttributeMapping`

`Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Super_Collection::_loadOptionLabels`

`Cm_RedisSession_Model_Session::read`

is taking too much time, as a result, the page is loading quite slow. Could you please advise us on the following:

Can we disable the configurable swatches on the checkout page / Shopping Cart page? Does it mean that only image will not be displayed on the Checkout page (Configurable Product)? What are the repercussions of this step?

What can be done for Redis Session? We are using FPC + Redis. Is it a configuration issue? What changes needs to be done to improvise the speed?